# hello my question is about matlab and its installation and when I want to stop the installation progress I found a problem which is :

Tags: matlab, software-installation

beside the progress bar I didn't get (X) for canceling so, is there any solution please !
because I need  matlab for my work thanks...

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you please edit your question and insert the error message you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu documentation is a good place to search for your need.

Please read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB) before and then if you still have a problem, state that and list the errors you have.